unable to dwonload zip file from google drive using gdown method in vs code
manually downloading openpose models
%%bash
gdown 1QCSxJZpnWvM00hx49CJ2zky7PWGzpcEh
unzip models.zip
mv /content/models/face/pose_iter_116000.caffemodel /content/openpose/models/face/pose_iter_116000.caffemodel
mv /content/models/hand/pose_iter_102000.caffemodel /content/openpose/models/hand/pose_iter_102000.caffemodel
mv /content/models/pose/body_25/pose_iter_584000.caffemodel /content/openpose/models/pose/body_25/pose_iter_584000.caffemodel
mv /content/models/pose/coco/pose_iter_440000.caffemodel /content/openpose/models/pose/coco/pose_iter_440000.caffemodel
mv /content/models/pose/mpi/pose_iter_160000.caffemodel /content/openpose/models/pose/mpi/pose_iter_160000.caffemodel
rm -rf models
rm models.zip
giving error like
gdown 1QCSxJZpnWvM00hx49CJ2zky7PWGzpcEh
^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
tried wget and curl method to perform the same task but still not worked.
it is working properly in colab notebooks but in Visual Studio code.

I feel like it could be to do with the link your using to find the file in google drive ?
Why don’t you use an actual link like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing
Obviously change FILE_ID to your files ID
And then do:
gdown --id YOUR_FILE_ID


still not working by giving same error
